# Difference in Output in Java and other Languages in generating subsequences

Tags: java, c++, arrays, subsequence

Update : My question is why do we need BigInteger in Java. Why can't we solve the question directly on the pseudocode as it workis in every other language.

This is the pseudocode for generating subsequences of a Array.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3} ;

int opsize = 2^size_of_array ;   

for (int counter = 1; counter < opsize; counter++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (counter & (1<<j))
            print(arr[j] + " ");
    }
    print new line ;
}
```

It is working for every language except Java. In every other language the output is

```
1 
2 
1 2 
3
1 3 
2 3
1 2 3
```

In Java, the code is

```
class Solution
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        int n = arr.length ; ;
        int res = (int) Math.pow(2,n);
        for(int i = 1 ; i < res ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j  < n ; j++)
                if ((i & (1<<j)) == 1 )
                    System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

In Java, the output for the same code is

```
1 

1 

1 

1
```

In Java, we need BigInteger to solve the same question

```
int opsize = (int)Math.pow(2, n);

    for (int counter = 1; counter < opsize; counter++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (BigInteger.valueOf(counter).testBit(j))
                System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: and .. your question is? you could do this without BigInteger, it would just take some other changes to your code. and, indeed, you can't call (instance) methods on primitive types

Comment: Other than the fact you are missing a question what you are saying is also completely wrong. The code executes just fine in Java without any usage of `BigInteger`. No idea what you are doing.

Comment: `n` just magically appears in your code?

Comment: I just assume that `n` is the size of the array. But yes, the magical appearance of varibles surely does not help.

Comment: So your C++ question is why some Java code you haven’t shown doesn’t do what you expect it to do?

Comment: In the Java code that you added, note that `== 1` is not the same as `!= 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the offending line of code:

```
if ((i & (1<<j)) == 1 )
```

This is not the same as `if (counter & (1<<j))` in C - in C, an integer is equivalent to a "true" condition if its value is *not zero*.

To correct this, you should write:

```
if ((i & (1<<j)) != 0)
```

After that change, the output is what you expected it to be.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I read the question a bit wrong.

The code without BigInteger has a problem:

```
if ((i & (1<<j)) == 1 )
```

In the bitshift, you shift by j. This is only true if j = 0 and i has the first bit set.

Suppose we have:

```
i=5
j=2
```

Then we do the bitshift an have following binary representations:

```
i = 0101
j = 0100
```

After AND operation we have:

```
0100
```

Which obviously does not satisfy the condition.

If you change it to:

```
if ((i & (1<<j)) > 0 )
```

It works, because the answer is > 0 if the specific bit defined by 1 << j is set.

EDIT: Removed the original answer which did not answer the question.

Comment: This isn’t an answer. He said that the `BigInteger` code works.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is bad:
`(i & (1<<j)) == 1`

It should be 
`(i & (1<<j)) != 0`

An exemple, for `i=6=0b0110`and `j=1=0b0001`:

```
1<<j == 2 == 0b0010
i & (1<<j) == 0b0110 & 0b0010 == 0b0010 == 2
```

Comment: The problem is that if you shift the bit into the Most Significant Bit (j == 31), then you get a negative number and your `> 0` condition fails. The equivalent of the C code is not `> 0` but `!= 0`.